# Open div on click drawingManager

Tags: google-maps, drawing, toggle

I would like to open a div (toggle) when i selectable marker or line in the drawing menu from google maps. In this way, data register with this marker or shape / line
Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

These buttons are not accessible via the API.

Possible workaround:

1. Initially set the `drawingMode` to `null`
2. observe the `drawingmode_changed`-event of the drawingManager(it will fire now when you select a `drawingMode` by clicking a menu-button). Show the div when this event fires and the `drawingMode` is either `marker` or `polyline`.
3. observe the `overlaycomplete`-event of the drawingManager and when it fires set the `drawingMode` back to `null`